# Zeppelin paragraphs using pyspark timing out after 1 hour

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin 0.8.2 in a docker container running Ubuntu 16.04

Long-running pyspark paragraphs all stop after exactly 1 hour, with a message like this:

`Took 1 hrs 0 min 0 sec. Last updated by anonymous at February 09 2021, 10:24:25 PM.`

I've confirmed spark is still running my code in the background, so it seems like the zeppelin connection to spark is cut off at the 1hr mark.

I tried editing the `zeppelin.interpreter.lifecyclemanager.timeout.threshold` variable in `zeppelin-site.xml` per [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/interpreter/overview.html#interpreter-lifecycle-management), but this has no effect on the issue even though the changes are clearly visible in the web ui ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T3zO.png)). Other values are set in that xml file that are read and executed by zeppelin. I also verified that the variables defined in `zeppelin-env.sh` were not conflicting with values set in the xml file.

Sometimes the paragraph output includes this error message:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:274)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:258)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$4.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:233)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$4.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:229)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:135)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:228)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:449)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have posted this on the official zeppelin issue tracker as well
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5279

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in v0.8.2 that was resolved in v0.9.0.